# Convertir hash en string

Tags: javascript

Tengo una función que convierte un string en un hash con la siguiente función:

```
String.prototype.hashCode = function() {
  var hash = 0, i, chr;
  if (this.length === 0) return hash;
  for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    chr   = this.charCodeAt(i);
    hash  = ((hash << 5) - hash) + chr;
    hash |= 0; // Convert to 32bit integer
  }
  return hash;
};
```

Funciona perfectamente, pero me gustaría saber como hacer lo contrario, a partir del hash que ha generado la función obtener el string.

Comment: Si realmente lo que genera ese código es un hash, entonces no tienes forma de obtener lo contrario. Normalmente un hash implica operaciones matemáticas sobre alguna entrada de donde se obtiene un resultado, pero no necesariamente del resultado se puede obtener la entrada... por ejemplo... si esas operaciones fueran sumar 3 numeros, yo puedo saber que 10 + 20 + 35 = 65... pero teniendo el 65 no puedo saber exactamente que numeros sumaron para obtener el 65, que podria haber sido 63 + 1 + 1 o 5 + 50 + 10... Si es un hash no se puede hacer la operacion inversa.

Comment: Entiendo @Pipe, gracias por la aclaración!!

Comment: Depronto si nos indicas para que necesitas realizar la operación inversa te podamos dar alguna alternativa

Comment: Con esa función almacenamos info de usuario, generamos el ID a partir del email para realizar determinadas acciones, pero he visto que alguna vez se genera más de un ID en la misma visita y quería comprobar de manera rápida haciendo el proceso inverso, que podía estar fallando.

Comment: La unica que se me ocurre es que la entrada cambie, porque dentro del código no veo que algo pueda cambiar. Es decir que quizas en algunos calculos uses "usuario@gmail.com" y en otro por alguna razón uses "usuario@gmail.com " (con espacio al final o con algun cambio que no sea tan visible) y eso haga que la entrada cambie y por eso genere un hash distinto

Comment: Algo de eso pensé, o que introduzca el email con algún error y al volverlo a meter bien duplique el hash